# Precison-recall calculation with no "true positive" data

Tags: confusion-matrix, precision-recall

I'm doing the segmentation task on medical images and trying to calculating the precision, recall with testing data. The label of images are 0(background) and 1(object).

The detection object will be very small or even no object in each slice in medical situation. So, if the label of some slices are all 0. No matter my prediction result is 0 or 1. The TP and will be 0. The confusion matrix will be something like this

```
     1    0
1    0    0 
0    5   95
```

The problem is the **precision and recall will be 0** because there are no positive class in label. The TP will be 0 and **the average recall and precision of total slices will be very low**

```
recall = TP / (TP+FN)

precision = TP/ (TP+FP)
```

How should I deal with these problem? And what if these situation is on multi-classification task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the confusion matrix for all the slices at once instead of averaging per slice results.

For multi-classification task you just do this process for each class because you want to know how each of the classes is segmented. So for example when you will look at first class, consider all the other classes as a background.

Comment: Do you mean to accumulate the confusion matrix(pixelwise) at once and then calculate the accurancy? Is this reasonable? I am not sure if the segmentation accurancy define like this. could you give me some reference?

Comment: Yes, I mean it. Since you are talking about slices I thought you have a 3D dataset. You can count the TP, FP, TN, FN over all slices. Which is the same as accumulating the confusion matrix.

Comment: I have 2 modules. one is for 2D medical segmentation and another is for 3D segmentation. Do you mean if I have 100 2D slices images validation data and I should accumulating the confusion matrix by these 100 data pixelwisely. Now the question is when I accumulate the confusion matrix, I will get a different accurancy if I calculate the accurancy in each slice and average for 100 data. I don't know which one is more reasonable and I will meet the problem like article mentioned in latter method .

Comment: Another question is that I have 2D and 3D segmentation modules,  is that the same way when I calculate the accurancy?

Comment: If you have 3D data it makes sense to accumulate the confusion matrix. Yes, the statistics is different therefore you always have to describe your process when you are giving the results. If 2D segmentation is a segmentation of 3D volume from 2D slices then it also make sense to calculate the accumulated confusion matrix.

Comment: Yes, I use 3D and 2D segmentation method to deal with the 3D medical image problems. Sorry for not telling this for. One more question, just to make sure I understand the right thing. If my dataset are 2D images, it doesn't make sense to accumulate the confusion matrix, right ? I should calculate the accurancy each image and average by all the images.

Comment: Yes. If it is 2D dataset then yes.